# Pymongo query on "subdocuments"

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Each instance of a collection called `groups` has a field called `actives`, which is a list of "subdocuments", i.e. things of the form {keys: values}. One field (key) of the subdocuments is `id_`, which is a string.

If I take the set of all subdocuments present in all the instances of `groups`, then there won't be 2 equal `id_`, i.e. `id_` identifies uniquely each subdocument. However, I get a new subdocument. I need to run a program with the subdocument's id that will go to a website and extract info about the subdocument. Within this info I find the group that the subdocument belongs to. However, I don't want to run this program if I already have some subdocument, in some instance of `groups` with the same `id_` as the "new" subdocument.

How can I list the ids of all the subdocuments of all the documents (or instances of `groups`)?

Edit:

Suppose that the documents of the DB groups are:

```
doc1: {"neighbourhood": "n1", "actives": [{"id_": "MHTEQ", "info": "a_long_string"}, {"id_": "PNPQA", "info": "a_long_string"}]}

doc2: {"neighbourhood": "n2", "actives": [{"id_": "MERVX", "info": "a_long_string"}, {"id_": "ZDKJW", "info": "a_long_string"}]}
```

What I want to do is to list all the `"id_"`, i.e.

```
def list_ids(groups):
    do_sth_with_groups
    return a_list

print(list_ids(groups))

output: ["MHTEQ", "PNPQA", "MERVX", "ZDKJW"]
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand without sample documents and the expected output. Please consider to provide additional infos.

Comment: @Styvane I have edited my question. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the aggregation pipeline with the `$unwind` and `$project` operators.

```
results = db['collection'].aggregate(
  [
    {"$project": {"actives": 1, "_id": 0}},
    {"$unwind": "$actives"},
    {"$project": {"id_str": "$actives.id_", "_id": 0}}
  ]
)
return list(results)
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Sample output

```
{ 
    "id_str" : "MHTEQ"
}
{ 
    "id_str" : "PNPQA"
}
{ 
    "id_str" : "MERVX"
}
{ 
    "id_str" : "ZDKJW"
}
```